# I have issues getting the data to submit for cart_chekout

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have issue getting data to submit or move on to the next page. I suspect its the while loop. trying to enter multiple data I am trying to enter multiple items to the data base with users information but a am not sure how to go about this. I know the code has not great and can get sql injections I am working on rewriting all the code.

cart.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Supplies</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://a0319p528/project2/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <script src="http://a0319p528/project2/assets/js/jquery2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://a0319p528/project2/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://a0319p528/project2/main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">   
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Supplies</a>
            </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window"></span>Product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8" id="cart_msg">
                <!--Cart Message--> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Cart Checkout</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Action</b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Product Image</b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Product Name</b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Quantity</b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Product Price</b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><b>Price in $</b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="cart_checkout"></div>
                        <!--<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><img src='product_images/imges.jpg'></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">Product Name</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type='text' class='form-control' value='1' ></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type='text' class='form-control' value='5000' disabled></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type='text' class='form-control' value='5000' disabled></div>
                        </div> -->
                        <!--<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Total $500000</b>
                            </div> -->
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

action.php

```
    <script src="assets/js/textboxname_autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <?php
    session_start();
    include "db.php";
    if(isset($_POST["category"])){
        $category_query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$category_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        echo "
            <div class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'><h4>Categories</h4></a></li>
        ";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $cid = $row["cat_id"];
                $cat_name = $row["cat_title"];
                echo "
                        <li><a href='#' class='category' cid='$cid'>$cat_name</a></li>
                ";
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["vendor"])){
        $vendor_query = "SELECT * FROM vendors";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$vendor_query);
        echo "
            <div class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'><h4>Vendors</h4></a></li>
        ";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $vid = $row["vendor_id"];
                $vendor_name = $row["vendor_title"];
                echo "
                        <li><a href='#' class='selectVendor' vid='$vid'>$vendor_name</a></li>
                ";
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["page"])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        $pageno = ceil($count/9);
        for($i=1;$i<=$pageno;$i++){
            echo "
                <li><a href='#' page='$i' id='page'>$i</a></li>
            ";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST["getProduct"])){

        $product_query = "SELECT * FROM products Order by product_title";
        $run_query = Mysqli_query($con, $product_query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) >0 ){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $pro_id = $row['product_id'];
                $pro_cat = $row['product_cat'];
                $pro_vendor = $row['product_vendor'];
                $pro_title = $row['product_title'];
                $pro_price = $row['product_price'];
                $pro_image = $row['product_image'];
                $pro_desc = $row['product_desc'];
                $pro_item_number = $row['product_item_number'];

                echo "
            <div class='col-md-4 '>
                <div class='panel panel-info'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>$pro_title</div>
                <div class='panel-body'>
                    <img src='assets/product_images/$pro_image' style ='width:100px; height:100px;'>
                    <p>$pro_desc</p>
                    <p>Item # $pro_item_number</p></div>
            <div class='panel-heading'>$.$pro_price.00
                <button pid='$pro_id' style='float:right;' id='product' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>AddToCart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";

            }
        }

    }
    if(isset($_POST["get_seleted_Category"]) || isset($_POST["selectVendor"]) || isset($_POST["search"])){
        if(isset($_POST["get_seleted_Category"])){
            $id = $_POST["cat_id"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat = '$id'";
        }else if(isset($_POST["selectVendor"])){
            $id = $_POST["vendor_id"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_vendor = '$id'";
        }else {
            $keyword = $_POST["keyword"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_keywords LIKE '%$keyword%'";
        }

        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $pro_id    = $row['product_id'];
                $pro_cat   = $row['product_cat'];
                $pro_vendor = $row['product_vendor'];
                $pro_title = $row['product_title'];
                $pro_price = $row['product_price'];
                $pro_image = $row['product_image'];
                $pro_item_number = $row['product_item_number'];

                    echo "
                <div class='col-md-4 box1'>
                <div class='panel panel-info'>
                    div class='panel-heading'>$pro_title</div>

                    <div class='panel-body'>
                            <img src='assets/product_images/$pro_image' style ='width:100px; height:100px;'>
                            <p>$pro_desc</p>
                            <p>Item # $pro_item_number</p></div>

                    <div class='panel-heading'>$.$pro_price.00
                    <button pid='$pro_id' style='float:right;' id='product' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>AddToCart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        ";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["addToProduct"])){

            if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
                $p_id = $_POST["proId"];
            $user_id = $_SESSION["uid"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE p_id = '$p_id' AND user_id = '$user_id'";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
            if($count > 0){
                echo "
                    <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                            <b>Product is already added into the cart Continue Shopping..!</b>
                    </div>
                ";//not in video
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$p_id'";
                $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
                    $id = $row["product_id"];
                    $pro_name = $row["product_title"];
                    $pro_image = $row["product_image"];
                    $pro_price = $row["product_price"];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `cart` 
                (`id`, `p_id`, `ip_add`, `user_id`, `product_title`,
                `product_image`, `qty`, `price`, `total_amt`)
                VALUES (NULL, '$p_id', '0', '$user_id', '$pro_name', 
                '$pro_image', '1', '$pro_price', '$pro_price')";
                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    echo "
                        <div class='alert alert-success'>
                            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                            <b>Product is Added..!</b>
                        </div>
                    ";
                }
            }
            }else{
                echo "
                        <div class='alert alert-success'>
                            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                            <b>Sorry..!go and Sign Up First then you can add a product to your cart</b>
                        </div>
                    ";
            }




        }
     //the issue starts here for the question I am asking.
    if(isset($_POST["get_cart_product"]) || isset($_POST["cart_checkout"])){
        $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$uid'";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        if($count > 0){
            $no = 1;
            $total_amt = 0;
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $id = $row["id"];
                $pro_id = $row["p_id"];
                $pro_name = $row["product_title"];
                $pro_image = $row["product_image"];
                $qty = $row["qty"];
                $pro_price = $row["price"];
                $total = $row["total_amt"];
                $price_array = array($total);
                $total_sum = array_sum($price_array);
                $total_amt = $total_amt + $total_sum;
                setcookie("ta",$total_amt,strtotime("+1 day"),"/","","",TRUE);
                if(isset($_POST["get_cart_product"])){
                    echo "
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'>$no</div>
                        <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'><img src='assets/product_images/$pro_image' width='60px' height='50px'></div>
                        <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'>$pro_name</div>
                        <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'>$.$pro_price.00</div>
                    </div>
                ";
                $no = $no + 1;
                }else{
                    echo "
                        <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'>
                                    <div class='btn-group'>
                                        <a href='#' remove_id='$pro_id' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                                        <a href='' update_id='$pro_id' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs update'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>";



                                echo"

                                <form action='user_information.php' id='form1' method='post'>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'><img src='assets/product_images/$pro_image' width='50px' height='60'></div>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'><input name='name' type='text' class='form-control qty' pid='$pro_name ' id='qty-$pro_name ' value='$pro_name ' ></div>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'><input name='qty' type='text' class='form-control qty' pid='$pro_id' id='qty-$pro_id' value='$qty' ></div>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'><input name='price' type='text' class='form-control price' pid='$pro_id' id='price-$pro_id' value='$pro_price' disabled></div>
                                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'><input name ='total' type='text' class='form-control total' pid='$pro_id' id='total-$pro_id' value='$total' disabled></div>
                            </div>";
                        }
                    }


                                echo"

                                    <h3>Employee Information</h3>
                                         <label>Lan ID</label>
                                        <input type='text' name='lanId' id='lanId'  autocomplete='off'  class='form-control' >
                                        <label>Employee Name</label>
                                        <input type='text' name='employeeName' id='name'   autocomplete='off'  class='form-control'>
                                        <label>Department</label>
                                        <select name='department' id='department'  class='form-control'>
                                            <option value =''>Select Department...</option>
                                            <option value ='OTHER'> OTHER</option>

                                        </select>

                                    <label>Cost Center</label>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='costCenter' value=''>
                                    <br><br><br>
                                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit'>

                                </form>";



            if(isset($_POST["cart_checkout"])){
                echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-8'></div>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                        <h1>Total $$total_amt</h1>
                    </div>";
            }
            echo '


                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">


                      ';

                      $x=0;
                      $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$uid'";
                      $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                          $x++;
                     echo  '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["product_title"].'">
                      <input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$x.'" value="'.$x.'">
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["price"].'">
                      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["qty"].'">';



                      }






        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST["cart_count"]) AND isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
        $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$uid'";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        echo mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["removeFromCart"])){
        $pid = $_POST["removeId"];
        $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$uid' AND p_id = '$pid'";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if($run_query){
            echo "
                <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                    <b>Product is Removed from Cart Continue Shopping..!</b>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST["updateProduct"])){
        $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
        $pid = $_POST["updateId"];
        $qty = $_POST["qty"];
        $price = $_POST["price"];
        $total = $_POST["total"];

        $sql = "UPDATE cart SET qty = '$qty',price='$price',total_amt='$total' 
        WHERE user_id = '$uid' AND p_id='$pid'";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if($run_query){
            echo "
                <div class='alert alert-success'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                    <b>Product is Updated Continue Shopping..!</b>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }

?>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    cat();
    vendor();
    product();
    function cat(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data    :   {category:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_category").html(data);

            }
        })
    }
    function vendor(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data    :   {vendor:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_vendor").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
        function product(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data    :   {getProduct:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_product").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    $("body").delegate(".category","click",function(event){
        $("#get_product").html("<h3>Loading...</h3>");
        event.preventDefault();
        var cid = $(this).attr('cid');

            $.ajax({
            url     :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {get_seleted_Category:1,cat_id:cid},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_product").html(data);
                if($("body").width() < 480){
                    $("body").scrollTop(683);
                }
            }
        })

    })
    $("body").delegate(".selectVendor","click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#get_product").html("<h3>Loading...</h3>");
        var vid = $(this).attr('vid');

            $.ajax({
            url     :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {selectVendor:1,vendor_id:vid},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_product").html(data);
                if($("body").width() < 480){
                    $("body").scrollTop(683);
                }
            }
        })

    })
    $("#search_btn").click(function(){
        $("#get_product").html("<h3>Loading...</h3>");
        var keyword = $("#search").val();
        if(keyword != ""){
            $.ajax({
            url     :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {search:1,keyword:keyword},
            success :   function(data){ 
                $("#get_product").html(data);
                if($("body").width() < 480){
                    $("body").scrollTop(683);
                }
            }
        })
        }
    })
    $("#signup_button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url     :   "register.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   $("form").serialize(),
            success :   function(data){ 
                $("#signup_msg").html(data);
            }
        })

    })
    $("#login").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var lanId = $("#lanId").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url :   "login.php",
            method: "POST",
            data    :   {userLogin:1,userLanId:lanId,userPassword:pass},
            success :function(data){
                if(data == "truefsvkjbskvvsbd"){
                    window.location.href = "profile.php";
                }
            }
        })
    })
    cart_count();
    $("body").delegate("#product","click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var p_id = $(this).attr('pid');
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {addToProduct:1,proId:p_id},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#product_msg").html(data);
                cart_count();
            }
        })
    })
    cart_container();
    function cart_container(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {get_cart_product:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#cart_product").html(data);
            }
        })

    };
    function cart_count(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {cart_count:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $(".badge").html(data);
            }
        })
    }

    $("#cart_container").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {get_cart_product:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#cart_product").html(data);
            }
        })

    })
    cart_checkout();
    function cart_checkout(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {cart_checkout:1},
            success : function(data){
                $("#cart_checkout").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    $("body").delegate(".qty","keyup",function(){
        var pid = $(this).attr("pid");
        var qty = $("#qty-"+pid).val();
        var price = $("#price-"+pid).val();
        var total = qty * price;
        $("#total-"+pid).val(total);
    })
    $("body").delegate(".remove","click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pid = $(this).attr("remove_id");
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {removeFromCart:1,removeId:pid},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#cart_msg").html(data);
                cart_checkout();
            }
        })
    })
    $("body").delegate(".update","click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pid = $(this).attr("update_id");
        var qty = $("#qty-"+pid).val();
        var price = $("#price-"+pid).val();
        var total = $("#total-"+pid).val();
        $.ajax({
            url :"action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {updateProduct:1,updateId:pid,qty:qty,price:price,total:total},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#cart_msg").html(data);
                cart_checkout();
            }
        })
    })
    page();
    function page(){
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {page:1},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#pageno").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    $("body").delegate("#page","click",function(){
        var pn = $(this).attr("page");
        $.ajax({
            url :   "action.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {getProduct:1,setPage:1,pageNumber:pn},
            success :   function(data){
                $("#get_product").html(data);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Where is `get_cart_product` and `cart_checkout` defined or passed?

Comment: sorry let me update the code add those parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your `<form>` inside your `else`, so if your `if` is correct, the form will never work.

Comment: I need to be able to grab all the multiple items in the while loop along with user info This seems to get much more complicated then I thought I may be trying something I am not sure of.

Comment: ok I think I understand what your saying so I moved it to employee information and it does work. I think I needed to figure how to grab the info from the else statement and put it in the form. the multiple items added to the cart.